# Having trouble with perspective and backface-visibility

Tags: css, css-transforms, perspective

I'd like to implement a "funny" Navigation into my website, with perspective and stuff, but, as a beginner, I look at a brick-wall.

I just don't find a way to get the line `backface-visibility: hidden;` working.

**My goal is:**

Front: 
[image: Front-Side]
Back:
[image: intended BACK-SIDE]

The result with the code below is (in rotation-state):
[image: resulting "back-side"]

There are plenty of working sample-codes on CodePen, and I tried to figure it out without success. Weird things happened, but never did the `backface-visibility` of an object get its `hidden`-state.

I used a great template to work on (designmodo.com) and trimmed it down to this:

#### HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="poster">
    <div class="layer-1">FRONT<img src="images/VS.svg" alt="Front" id="FRONT"></div>
    <div class="layer-2">BACK<img src="images/RS.svg" alt="Back" id="BACK"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
body {
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform:perspective(1500px);
}

.poster {
  width:510px;
  height:310px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin:-156px 0 0 -256px;
  border-radius:4px;
  box-shadow:0 45px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.layer-1, .layer-2 {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transform:translateZ(10px);
  backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.layer-2 {
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Please see my pen: https://codepen.io/herrbraun/pen/JKroYa
(the rotation is there **only to show the not-working `blackface-visibility`** –– once it works, it'll be interactive)

If somebody could have an eye on what I've got so far, I don't see any typos or syntax-errors, but – what makes the CSS "fail"?

Comment: Provide us with the code that you have tried and tell us what it doesn't do that you want it to. Show us your effort and only then can we help you.

While you did provide codepen, you should also provide bare-bones snippet that reproduces your problem, instead of just posting a link. 

Also, you should explain a little better what exactly is the problem, as I find it hard to decipher actual problem here.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want? Be precise

Comment: maybe this demo from w3schools helps you understand what backface-visibility does http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/trycss3_backface_inuse.htm

if you rotate an element you will see the element with interchanged sides or you will see nothing (backface-visibility: hidden)

Comment: Yes. I knew that and wanted to use it. (My goal is to have sort of a "card", with a front and a back. the back is `transform:rotateY(180deg);`, so that when the card is _turned / rotated_, the back-side show actually not the mirrored front-, but the backside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have a syntax error:

```
.layer-1, layer-2 {
```

should be

```
.layer-1, .layer-2 {
```

Also, for this setup to work, you need to set

```
.poster {
    transform-style: preserve-3D;
}
```

because you have transforms both in the parent and the child, and you want get the backface style to the combination of both. You had already this on *body*, but this property doesn't inherit.

Your snippet corrected

```css
body {
 transform-style:preserve-3d;
 transform:perspective(1500px);
}
@keyframes rotating {
    from{
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    to{
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}

.poster {
    animation: rotating 10s linear infinite;
}

.poster {
 width:510px;
 height:310px;
 position:absolute;
 top:50%;
 left:50%;
 margin: 0 0 0 -256px;
 border-radius:4px;
 box-shadow:0 45px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  transform-style: preserve-3D; /* new */
}

.poster .shine {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%);
 background:linear-gradient(135deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%);
 z-index:100;
}

.layer-1, .layer-2 {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 transform: translateZ(10px);
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: .1s;
 transition: .1s;
}
.layer-1 {background-color: blue; color:white;}
.layer-2 {
  background-color: red;
 transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
  <div class="poster">
  <div class="layer-1">FRONT<img src="images/VS.svg" alt="Front" id="FRONT"></div>
  <div class="layer-2">BACK<img src="images/RS.svg" alt="Back" id="BACK"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Vals! I just got back from a 5-day holiday. Your correction (`transform-style: preserve-3D`is perfect. Now I'll move to the next level, making it interactive :-) ! I hope I won't need to get back for this... many thanks, david

Comment: Happy that it helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the animation to `.layer-1` and `.layer-2` instead of `.poster` and set the `animation-delay` of `.layer-2` to `-5s`

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. Just went to try, doesn't work. (see [link](https://davidbraun.ch/parallaxing/index.html) )

Comment: Noteworthy: I removed an additional `<div`inside the `.poster`, and – when applying the `backface-visibilty` to the `.poster`, it hides the backfire altogether...

Comment: Ok, I understand your problem now, I think I have an idea how to solve it

Comment: Uhm. Chrome now shows the backside only, while safari goes nuts (kinda mixes between "frontside-only" and "show poster but no childs" -> see on top of Question

Comment: Totally works for me: [Demo](https://codecanister.com/Project/d547eed9/14/result/)

Comment: I see. Yes it does. I'll take this as a hint to search what makes my version fail. (I guess it is something with the combination of `blackface-visibility` and `rotateY` of `.layer-2`) –– thanks!

Comment: I used the stylesheet live on your site + my code(you can see in the demo)